# Generating filesystem paths from a fixed string

Tags: python

It's clever, but makes me vomit a little:

```
file = '0123456789abcdef123'

path = os.sep.join([ file[ x:(x+2) ] for x in range(0,5,2) ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but it looks like you're splitting a string into groups of two a specified number of times? Despite the magic constants, etc. there's really no better way to **do** it, but I think there's certainly a better way to format it (I'm assuming these are directories since you're using os.sep):

The below is I think a more clear way to write it:

```
file = '0123456789abcdef123'
dir_len = 2
path_len = 3

path = os.sep.join(file[ x:(x+2) ] for x in range(0, dir_len * path_len-1, dir_len))
```

Note that the [] around the list comprehension is gone - it's now a [generator](http://linuxgazette.net/100/pramode.html). For this example it really doesn't matter which one you use, but since this is Code Review generators are another Python concept you should look at.

Answer (score 10):

Is there are reason you're not just doing:

```
path = os.sep.join([file[0:2], file[2:4], file[4:6]])
```

I think that my version is a little easier to parse (as a human), but if you need to extend the number of groups, your code is more extensible.

Edit: and if we're looking for things that are easy to read but not necessarily the best way to do it...

```
slash = os.sep
path = file[0:2] + slash + file[2:4] + slash + file[4:6]
```